# Pausing execution until writeStringToFile is finished

Tags: java, io, apache-commons

I have a line that writes a string to a file using [apache commons io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20boolean)):

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, doc.outerHtml(), "UTF-8", false);
```

I believe that execution is continuing even before the file has been completely written.

I don't want the execution to progress until this file has been written. Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Like this?

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class WriteFile implements Runnable {
private CountDownLatch latch;

public WriteFile(CountDownLatch latch) {
    this.latch = latch;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Started.");
    // Do something - in this case write to file
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, doc.outerHtml(), "UTF-8", false);
    latch.countDown();
}
```

Then in the parent code:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.submit(new WriteFile(latch));

    try {
        latch.await();  // wait until latch counted down to 0
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Completed.");
```

Comment: Is that method call a *blocking* call? What does the API state?

Comment: Use a second thread, use it to call `FileUtils.writeStringToFile`.  Use a `Semaphore` or `CountDownLatch` or monitor lock to control the flow between the two threads

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. These are concepts I have not used previously. Do you have a link to a example?

Comment: @AlGrant [Concurrency in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) - I'd also test the call, as most write operations are already blocking